# Follow user using twitter framework

Tags: api, twitter

Could you explain me how to follow someone using twitter api?
I'm a begginer and I don't know how to do this!

Thanks!

Miquel Àngel Rigo Vidal

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started is to use an existing library. Here's a list on Twitter's site you can use. Find something written for a programming language you're familiar with:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Alternatively, look at the HTTP libraries available for the programming language you use and write code to make an HTTP request.  In the case of following another user, you would create an HTTP POST request for a URL specified accoring to the Twitter documentation for friendships/create:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create

Since this requires authentication, as specified in the friendships/create docs above, you'll have to use OAuth, which you can learn more about here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs

If writing your own HTTP and OAuth code sounds too hard, then look at the list of libraries above to see what you can do.

Joe